# Change placeholder color in Javascript for Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, css

As said here : [Change an HTML5 input's placeholder color with CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2610497/change-an-inputs-html5-placeholder-color-with-css), Chrome doesn't support the CSS property color for input placeholders.

But there is a property named `-webkit-input-placeholder`. If I put on my CSS :

```
#MyInput::-webkit-input-placeholder {
    color: blue;
}
```

It works. But how can I do this with Javascript (or jQuery) ?

Comment: Define it in the CSS as you have it, but make it `#MyInput.blue-placeholder::-webkit-input-placeholder` and add/remove the "blue-placeholder" class with jQuery.

Comment: Yes, it's a solution that I had not thought, thank you. I'm still looking for direct solutions. Meanwhile, I take this one !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Define it in the CSS as you have it, but make it `#MyInput.blue-placeholder::-webkit-input-placeholder` and add/remove the "blue-placeholder" class with jQuery.

```
#MyInput.blue-placeholder::-webkit-input-placeholder {
    color: #0000ff;
}
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/AY3j6/

Comment: Thank you for the demo, I didn't know toggleClass. I can accept your answer in 5 minutes. ;)

Comment: @Arnaud No problem. The `toggleClass` was just for an example. You can use `addClass` and `removeClass` as well

Comment: @Arnaud Sounds good :) Glad you learned about it and can use it. If it helps, even though it's pretty straightforward, here's the docs for it: http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/

Comment: @Dex Hmm I just tested on Safari 6.2 and it works fine. You understand you have to click the button, right? If you have a question about setting the placeholder color, you might want to search or ask a new question. This question was specifically about toggling the color with JavaScript/jQuery - my solution was to just target and toggle a class, which should work in any browser (especially with jQuery). Your version of Safari may not support the `::-webkit-input-placeholder`, which this question isn't about. I wish I knew more about Safari or could help